# I need help using SED to replace values in the third set of parenthesis

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

So I am still a noob with Bash/scripting. I am working on a project that will automate the process of grabbing account keys and place them in a specific set of parenthesis of a SQL query line that will be housed in a separate text file. I've figured out what I've needed up to this point but I am unsure of how to replace the values for a specific parenthesis.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT NOW(),COUNT (*) FROM ACCT_HIST WHERE ACCT_KEY IN (1010000) AND REC_ACTV_IND = 'Y' AND DT_KEY < 20191009;
```

So I only want to replace the parenthesis value after "ACCT_KEY IN". How can I do this?

I get the gist of replacing values in a parenthesis using something like:

```
"sed "s/([^)]*)/()/g" filename
```

but I am unsure of how to avoid replacing data in ALL parenthesis. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You have multiple questions with answers, but you did neither feed-back or accept one. Kindly reminder: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

To replace the third occurrence of `([^)]*)` with `()`:

```
sed "s/([^)]*)/()/3"
```

For example:

```
$ sed "s/([^)]*)/()/3" <<< "(1) (2) (3) (4);"
(1) (2) () (4);
```

To replace the last occurrence:

```
$ sed "s/\(.*\)([^)]*)/\1()/" <<< "(1) (2) (3) (4) etc;"
(1) (2) (3) () etc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 sed 's/\(.*ACCT.*(\)\([0-9]\{2,\}\)\().*\)/\1your_value_to_replace\3/g'
```

You can create 3 regex grouping words in your query using escaped parenthesis to differentiate the groups :

- 1st group : .*ACCT.*( means everything from beginning then ACCT then everything until opening parenthesis.
- 2nd : [0-9]{2,} meaning numbers between 0 to 9 at least 2 times
- 3rd group : ).* the rest after closing parenthesis

Then you substitute only the second group (\2) and keep the first (\1) and third (\3) which give you the following syntaxe : \1whatever\3